# what does lifetime without a variable attached mean?

Tags: rust

```
fn hello<'a>() {}
```

In rust, can a function have its own lifetime?
I ran into a piece of code as below

```
struct Hi {}

async fn wrapper<'a, F, Fut>(f: F) 
where 
Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
F: FnOnce(&'a mut Hi) -> Fut{

}
```

but couldn't understand what lifetime 'a could mean here...

Comment: the lifetime is not for the function, but for the argument of its argument here, namely "Hi".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the lifetime name appear as part of the function type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837398/why-does-the-lifetime-name-appear-as-part-of-the-function-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can a function have its own lifetime?

Functions don't have lifetimes; references do. But you can have a reference to a function. And you can have a lifetime as a parameter of a function.

> couldn't understand what lifetime `'a` could mean here.

It just means it's a mutably borrowed parameter of closure with lifetime `&'a`.

In essence, `async fn wrapper<F, Fut>(f: F)` behaves the same, since `&' a` can be elided.

It would be useful if, somewhere inside the function's code, you needed to say lifetime `'a` will outlive some lifetime `'b`.

For example:

```rust
async fn wrapper<'a, 'b, F, Fut>(f: F, b: &'b Hi)
where
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
    F: FnOnce(&'a mut Hi) -> Fut,
    'a : 'b
```